# Add links widget to self-hosted blog?

Tags: widgets

http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/links-widget/ discusses a Links widget that makes it easy to create a blogroll in your sidebar. I'm not seeing this widget in my blog by default, and searching the plugins available is not turning it up. Is this feature available to self-hosted blogs? How, if so? Or is this one of those features only available to wordpress.com sites and I'll just have to find another similar widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links were removed from standard Wordpress in 3.5 I believe. To add them, use the [Links Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/link-manager/) plugin - I believe this will enable the Links widget as well.

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it.